# Idetifying equivalent regular expressions

Tags: regex

I am revising for am exam and one of the topics is regular expressions.

A past exam paper has the question

> Which of the following regular expressions are equivalent? Explain
>   your reasoning. [8 Marks]
>
> (i) (a+b)* b (a+b)* b (a+b)*
>
> (ii) a* b a* b a*
>
> (iii) a* b a* b (a+b)*

I think its a trick question and the answer is none because

i will accept aabaabaabaabbaabaabaabaabbaabaabaabaab but ii and iii wont

then because ii can only accept 2 b's maximum and iii can accept 2 b's as a minimum.

Am I correct or have I got this completely wrong?

I have e-mailed my lecturer for help but had no reply so I'm hoping someone here can help.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried drawing the equivalent state machine and reducing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`i` and `iii` are equivalent.

The regular expressions are both "a string of `a`s and `b`s where there are at least two `b`s" (this should be clear from each definition). The fact that `iii` just has `a*`s in place of the first two `(a+b)*` is a distraction. I'll break down how `iii` describes the string:

- a possibly empty string of `a`s (`A` in the labelling below)
- the first `b`  (`X`)
- another possibly empty string of `a`s (`B`)
- a second `b` (`Y`)
- and the rest of the string which is just a mix of `a`s and `b`s (`C`)

For your example, `iii` does match it. Imagine we labelled the regular expression like so (the `v` and `^` are just arrows):

```
A  X B  Y   C
vv v vv v vvvvvv 
a* b a* b (a+b)*
```

Then we can label which part of the regex corresponds to the parts of the string:

```
  X  Y
  v  v
aabaabaabaabbaabaabaabaabbaabaabaabaab
^^ ^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
A   B            C
```

(@Li-aungYip's suggestion is a good one too.)

Comment: i and iii are definitely not equivalent. Regex iii will match "abb", but regex i will not match "abb".

Comment: @Alderath, I'm almost certain it will. You will have to give more details about why it doesn't match.

Comment: Besides, your translation of subexpression C into words ("just a mix of as and bs") is plain wrong. Subexpression C does not allow for two consecutive b:s for example, so it will not match the sequence `aabaabbaabaabaabaabbaabaabaabaab`, as implied by your example.

Comment: @Alderath, this is a (more) theoretical regex question, so I was assuming `+` means alternation (like `|`) rather than one-or-more.

Comment: If it says "which of the following regular expressions", I think it is quite safe to assume that the expressions that follow have correct regex syntax, not some arbitrary semi-pseudocode representation of regexes.

Comment: That's not arbitrary pseudocode, from [wikipedia in the formal language section on REs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Formal_language_theory): "Many textbooks use the symbols ∪, +, or ∨ for alternation instead of the vertical bar". In an regex engine, `A+` is just a shorthand way of writing `AA*`.

Comment: My apologies. My limited experiences with regexes have only involved the code interpreted by regex engines. I never studies text books about the subject. Your answer is definitely correct then. I still feel that it is a bit weird that they use different meanings of the + sign for text box regexes and regex code though, but that’s a completely different issue. +1 for teaching me something about regex representations.

Comment: No problem :) happy to help! (Even knowing both interpretations, I always have to stop myself reflexively reading `+` as one-or-more for questions like these, so don't worry!)

Comment: @Alderath `a*ba*b(a+b)*` will be a match for the string `aabaabbaabaabaabaabbaabaabaabaab`. You are assuming the regex pattern starts with ^ and ends with $.

Comment: i and iii are definitely not the same. i requires 2 b's in a row somewhere in the string, iii just allows it.

Comment: @Nick, i matches `ababa`. (If you are interpreting `a+b` as one-or-more `a`s followed by one `b`, please read the discussion directly preceding your comment.)

Comment: @dbaupp in the link you provided under **Formal definition** it says + means one or more, and has 1 little sentence that says some text books don't follow that standard while the rest of the entire page says that + means one more. So that only helps to support `+` meaning `or` *is* abitrary pseudocode.

Comment: @Nick. 1) This question and answer are months old. 2) It might be uncommon, but it's not arbitrary (and anyway, the quote is "Many textbooks use the symbols..." so it's not even uncommon to use `+`, and there is no "standard" for how to represent formal regexes). 3) The questioner accepted the answer, so presumably they understand what I'm talking about in the context of their course. 4) I assume that it wouldn't be a trick question.